How would I translate GPT to German?
Large language models like GPTs are everywhere nowadays. A GPT is a "generative pre-trained transformer". How would I best translate this into German?

generative: erzeugend (meaning that it creates stuff)
pre-trained: vortrainiert (meaning that there was a training phase based on existing material)
transformer: ?

Here are my thoughts about transformer:

Transformator: is too much bound to electrical things
Wandler: GPTs don't change text, they append new text to existing text
Umformer: GPTs don't change text, they append new text to existing text
Umspanner: is too much bound to electrical things
Übertrager: for me, this involves getting things from one place to another (like one coil to another, or from one idea to another)

From what such a GPT or LLM does, I'd rather have a word like "predictor" (because it predicts the next plausible character (token)) or "complementor" (because it completes sentences).
What translation of "transformer" could I use, so that it is not too far from transformer but still describes the thing so that it can be understood? Is "erzeugende, vortrainierte Vervollständigung" too far off?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

I suggest you don't try to translate and instead use GPT.
I'm sure 99% of English speakers don't know what GPT means, except that it is related to artificial intelligence. The same applies to Germans (and others).
If you want to address those who have a deeper understanding, it is safe to assume that they are familiar with the technical term. Translating it would make your text actually harder to understand, because the reader would have to pause and think "What is the meaning of this? Oh, it's about GPT."
As some of the comments noted, the words for GPT don't really express the concept that well. That should be no surprise, as I don't think such a complex concept can be expressed in any few words.
In general I don't recommend to attempt to translate technical terms, except if you know that there is already an established translated technical term.
Historical example: I once read a technical documentation in perfect German grammar (very rare), but it translated two unrelated terms, "break" and "interrupt", as "Unterbrechung". Exercise for the reader: Find out what the word "Unterbrechung" means each time it is used.

It does not make sense to translate the word Transformer, as it is only a (more or less) arbitrary name the researchers choose for a new computational architecture.
The name Transformer was choosen by the authors of the paper

Ashish Vaswani, Noam Shazeer, Niki Parmar, Jakob Uszkoreit, Llion Jones, Aidan N Gomez, Łukasz Kaiser, Illia Polosukhin: Attention is All you Need. In: Advances in Neural Information Processing Systems. Curran Associates, Inc., 2017

The article contains no explanation for the term. Instead everything they want to say about it is in the introduction:

In this work we propose the Transformer, a model architecture eschewing recurrence and instead relying entirely on an attention mechanism to draw global dependencies between input and output.

and the conclusion:

In this work, we presented the Transformer, the first sequence transduction model based entirely on attention, replacing the recurrent layers most commonly used in encoder-decoder architectures with multi-headed self-attention.

The technical terms used to describe the model are "sequence transduction" and "attention", and it is contrasted with older models based on "recurrence" / "recurrent layers".
Even without really understanding the terms, there is not one hint how those concepts lead the authors to choose the word "transformer".
I agree with the authors of the German Wikipedia article that Generativer vortrainierter Transformer is the best way to refer to these models in a German-language text.

Never translate technical terms!
All native German speakers (more than 99%) who use AI tools or just talk about them are multilingual. They speak not only standard German and their local German dialect, but also fluent English. We all had between 4 and 12 years of English in school, depending on the year we were born and the type of school we attended. More than 90% of the songs we hear on the radio have English lyrics. Many German-speaking users of YouTube, TikTok and similar platforms watch videos in English.
Thousands of English words and phrases have become part of the German vocabulary in the last 80 years since World War II. We are so used to English terms and abbreviations of English terms, especially when they come from a technical environment, that we would be very confused if we came across a real German technical term.
So please never try to translate names of algorithms, names of applications and names of devices from English into German.
The question of using anglicisms in German can be a means of social or political positioning. Consequently using germanizations of widespread anglicisms might be perceived as a shibboleth and can lead to being put into a political bucket.

Was mich manchmal verwirrt ist wie heutzutage Begriffe auf Deutsch nicht übersetzt werden. Bsp., im Bereich Technologie, vorher hat man ein "Hard drive"als Festplatte bezeichnet, aber jetzt werden neue Technologien auf den englischen Begriffen verwiesen, zB wie "USB-Stick". Was könnte der Grund dafür sein?

@rasengan__: Die Kommentare auf Antworten auf andere Fragen sind nicht der richtige Ort, um neue Fragen zu stellen. Folge stattdessen bitte diesem Link: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/ask



Wandler: GPTs don't change text, they append new text to existing text
Umformer: GPTs don't change text, they append new text to existing text


Actually, transformers and GPT are two different, yet related things. A transformer consists of an encoder and decoder part. The encoder takes a sequence (sentence) and computes a vector embedding for it, the decoder computes a sequence (sentence) from this vector embedding. See the original publication for more details. That means, the transformer transforms a sequence. Hence, I do find the German expressions "Umformer" and "Wandler" actually very fitting translations for "transformer". Note also that the transformer architecture was originally proposed for machine translation, where sentences are transformed from one language into another.
Based on this transformer architecture, other models have been proposed. BERT only uses the encoder part of the transformer and computes a latent representation for an input sequence. GPT, on the other hand, only uses the decoder part of the transformer.
Although it still transforms sentences at its core - that is to discard the first token (word) and append a new token at the end - the translation "Umformer" might not seem very fitting for what it does on a high level. From this perspective, I think the most fitting term would be "Generator" or "Erzeuger", but we already have this covered by "generative".
When we look at the name "Generative Pre-Trained Transformer" from this background, we find that, "transformer" actually does not describe what it does, but rather what it is - a transformer-based model. Consequently, I believe that, in line with the other answers, the term "transformer" is best left untranslated.
Note also that the term "transformer" might also refer to the movie "transformers". In this area of research, it's not uncommon to see references to pop culture and works like Megatron-LM and Galvatron build upon this.
